# Can't unzip the chrome webdriver of selenium for python3.5

Tags: python3, selenium

I was trying to install the chrome webdriver for ubuntu 16.04, but every since I download it (it's a zip file) and extract by right-clicking and selecting "extract here" its giving me a text file, not a directory, as usual.

So, I was curious about it and decided to open it, but it can't be opened. Always when I try it gives me the follow pop-up :

```
Impossible to open "Chromedriver"

There is no application installed for “shared library” files.
Do you want to search for an application to open this file?
```

(that part was translated by google translator, so can have some differences between the original text and this one)

So, I want to know why its giving me a text file
and how to install it correctly.

Additional informations :

I am using the 85.0.4183.83 version of chrome

Installed the chromedriver 85.0.4183.83

If possible, tell how to do it by using user interface, not by terminal

Comment: Exact what commands are you using to open the file ?

Comment: I tried changing to the directory that I did the dowload, by using "cd /path/to/chrome/zip/file" and tried to unzip it by using "unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip ", to short the story, I could unzip it, but its giving me a text file. And to open the text file at the time I did this, I just tried to open in gedit, but it crashes every time I try, then I tried to open in geany, just to see if there is code, but it couldn't open it, it's a binary, by the way